# Quick-start to journalism?

Tags: journalism

I currently was given an amazing opportunity to interview with some of my favorite idols, but I don't have much experience writing journalism.
As in, I literally have written one article in the entire existence.
However, through some contacts, I was able to land an opportunity to write for a magazine which I currently read. They want a writing sample and I honestly don't have any any good journalism articles.

I want to get some articles in within 2 days (At the end of Wednesday)

My articles will be about:

- Interviews
- J-pop music scene
- Specific music artists
- Mobile gaming and specific games/companies

They will be both in print and online.

What are some resources that I can read to get to know the style of writing and vocabulary? I'm coming from a computer science background so this is pretty out of my comfort zone.

Are there experienced writers whom I can pay to critique my articles?

If not any of the above, can you guys recommend some writers from newspapers that you love?

That way I can read and learn from them

Comment: If I was you I'd stop looking at this site and start writing. To get the job you need to actually produce something.

Comment: As in all writing cases, the best is probably to *read* article similar to what you want to write and see why they are good or bad. In particular in your targeted magazines.

Comment: I am also from a computer field. This is not a stack overflow where you get solutions for your program. Use your contacts , like Friends whom you trust the moat and they are interested for criticism. Do workout on twitter too.

Answer (score 2):

Really, the samples you want to read are from the magazine you're about to write for. Those are the readers you need to satisfy.

Which articles catch your eye? Which articles get you to read all the way through?

The basics of journalism writing are pretty easy. Start right out with the conclusion of your article and then add specifics. It's the upside-down pyramid style and it's worked forever, designed to let someone read an article, get the important information immediately and then read as far as they remain interested.

You also can start with an anecdotal lead, a quote from someone, or a few lines to set the tone before diving into the article. Or write it in a list form. Interviews start with a description of the interviewee and then follow a pretty standard q&a format.

Once you're practiced enough, start breaking some of those rules and see what sort of style you can develop for yourself.

A quick guide: [News writing tips for beginners](http://www.mediahelpingmedia.org/training-resources/journalism-basics/464-assembling-a-news-story)